# Is it possible to have multiple colourbars in plotly 3D surface plot and position them individually?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to plot a 3D surface plot that has two surfaces - one showing a set of data defined as above average returns and another defined as below average returns.

The logic of the chart being I want to see for a give X, Y and Z characteristic (my 3 axes), what will be the point at which I have the max divergence in above and below average returns.

To visualise this in a way that is les confusing as some point overlap, I want to seperate the two surface colours in two colourbars and position them so that you can see the different bars. My current approach is not working and I seem to just overlap the titles of the same colourbar.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Surface(
        z=pivot_above.values, 
        x=pivot_above.columns, 
        y=pivot_above.index,
        cmin=z_min, 
        cmax=z_max, 
        name='Above Avg Return', 
        opacity=0.6,
        colorscale='Viridis',  
        showlegend=True
    ),
    go.Surface(
        z=pivot_below.values, 
        x=pivot_below.columns, 
        y=pivot_below.index, 
        cmin=z_min, 
        cmax=z_max,
        name='Below Avg Return', 
        opacity=1,
        colorscale='Cividis',  
        showlegend=True
    )
])

z_zero = [[0 for _ in range(len(pivot_above.columns))] for _ in range(len(pivot_above.index))]
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(
    z=z_zero, 
    x=pivot_above.columns, 
    y=pivot_above.index, 
    cmin=z_min, 
    cmax=z_max,
    showscale=False,
    name='Zero Return Level',
    opacity=0,
    colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [1, 'green']]
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='3D Surface Plot for Mean EUA DoD % Change For Upper and Lower Thresholds',
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='Upper Quartile',
        yaxis_title='Lookback',
        zaxis_title='Return'
    ),
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        thickness=20,
        len=0.8,
        title='Unified Scale', 
        tickfont=dict(size=12)
    ),
    width=800,
    height=800,
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To move the second color bar, the following code is valid. `fig.data[1]['colorbar']['x'] = 0.8` I used the development function to get all the set values for the graph and changed the position of the second color bar, since the color bar has the same settings in 1.02. `full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development();print(full_fig)`

Comment: You can set `colorbar_x` directly in the `go.Surface()` constructor.